# How to execute /bin/sh with commons-exec?

Tags: java, apache-commons-exec

This is what I'm doing:

```
import org.apache.commons.exec.*;
String cmd = "/bin/sh -c \"echo test\"";
new DefaultExecutor().execute(CommandLine.parse(cmd));
```

This is the output:

```
/bin/sh: echo test: command not found
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What platform is this? Linux? Is `/bin/sh` bash or dash, or is it some shell that does not have `echo` as a builtin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one works for me:-

```
    CommandLine command = new CommandLine("/bin/sh");
    command.addArguments(new String[] {
            "-c",
            "echo 'test'"
    },false);
    new DefaultExecutor().execute(command);
```

Comment: Does not do the same thing as in the question. This would execute `/bin/echo` with the argument `test` instead of `/bin/sh` with the arguments `-c` and `echo test`. They are different because `echo` is also built into `/bin/sh`.

Comment: @limc it works, but it's not the point to make this particular example working. The point is to provide a complex argument into external process, which I can't do so far..

Comment: @yegor256: Did you look at my corrected version before you marked me down?

Comment: @yegor256: Wait, what complex argument? Are you trying to do something beyond `echo test` ?

Comment: When calling `command.addArguments()`, set the quote handling to false.

Comment: @limc that's the solution (`,false` argument), thanks! Now it works. I can't remove the down-vote, unless you edit your answer a bit. Please do this and I will upvote instead.

Comment: I just spent some time reading through the source of commons-exec, and it appears that it goes full retard if you don't provide `false` for the `handleQuoting` parameter wherever possible. Really awful design, IMHO.

Answer (score 8):

According to [the FAQ](http://commons.apache.org/exec/faq.html#complex-quoting) "It is recommended to use `CommandLine.addArgument()` instead of `CommandLine.parse()`".

So try

```
CommandLine commandLine = new CommandLine("/bin/sh");
commandLine.addArgument("-c");
commandLine.addArgument("echo test", false); // false is important to prevent commons-exec from acting stupid
executor.execute(commandLine);
```

Comment: Are you sure you didn't add any extra quotes?

Comment: Positive. I'm using exactly the example you provided.

Comment: Passing `false` is critical here. I even tried `commandLine.addArgument("\"echo test\"")`, but I get exit code 127, which indicates that bash couldn't execute it.

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce your problem from a shell command line:

```
# /bin/sh -c '"echo test"'
# /bin/sh: echo test: command not found
```

I'd say you should try to not quote the command.

Comment: How to group `echo` and `test` than?

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.apache.commons.exec.*; 

CommandLine commandLine = new CommandLine("abc.sh");
commandLine.addArgument("param1"); 
final Executor exec = new DefaultExecutor().execute(commandLine);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

The command doesn't work because commons-exec doing unnecesary quoting of all arguments, which have space or quote.

This unnecessary quoting of arguments is controlled by `handleQuoting` flag of each argument. If you create the `CommandLine` object using it's constructor and `addArgument` methods, you can set this flag to `false`.

Like this:

```
CommandLine commandLine = new CommandLine("/bin/sh");
commandLine.addArgument("-c");
commandLine.addArgument("echo test", false);
```

(*The important part is `false` as second argument of `addArgument` method*)

And it works! But... it is unconvinient to construct command line manually instead of having it defined in some config file.

`CommandLine.parse` always sets the `handleQuoting` flag to true! Who knows why...

I wrote this small helper method using reflection to fix "bad" `CommandLine` object, created using `CommandLine.parse`.

```
public static CommandLine fixCommandLine(CommandLine badCommandLine) {
    try {
        CommandLine fixedCommandLine = new CommandLine(badCommandLine.getExecutable());
        fixedCommandLine.setSubstitutionMap(badCommandLine.getSubstitutionMap());
        Vector<?> arguments = (Vector<?>) FieldUtils.readField(badCommandLine, "arguments", true);
        arguments.stream()
                .map(badArgument -> {
                    try {
                        return (String) FieldUtils.readField(badArgument, "value", true);
                    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }
                })
                .forEach(goodArgument -> fixedCommandLine.addArgument(goodArgument, false));
        return fixedCommandLine;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Cannot fix bad command line", e);
        return badCommandLine;
    }
}
```

It just clones the given `CommandLine`, setting each argument's `handleQuoting` flag to `false`.
The method `FieldUtils.readField` is from commons-lang3 library, but you can use plain reflection if you want.

It allows to parse command line and still successfully execute it.

```
String cmd = "/bin/sh -c 'echo test'";
new DefaultExecutor().execute(fixCommandLine(CommandLine.parse(cmd)));
```